# 64 bit NASM - retrieve element of 2D array

Tags: arrays, assembly, multidimensional-array, nasm

I need to retrieve element of 2D array in NASM - array is 50x60 chars, statically allocated. r13 stores array's width, rsi contains address of the beginning, r8 and r9 are indexes (they correspond to the first and the second coordinate accordingly). I have tried running:

```
imul r8, r13
mov rax, [rsi + (r8 + r9) * 8]
```

but it doesn't work - I get `beroset-p-603-invalid effective address`. How to fix it?

Comment: You can answer your own question... you should do that, you'll get some rep too.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

All right, I have managed to do this. This code was a modified copy paste from an older version of this program, where I was using dynamically allocated memory. So if anyone else get this error, here is how I have solved it:

```
mov r15, rsi ; duplicate the pointer, so it's not destroyed by the following operation
imul r8, r13
add r15, r8
mov rax, [r15 + r9]
```

Compiles and seems to work